# Add a mean and 3*std to a scatter plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, std, mean

I've got a scatter plot and want add a straight line for mean, 3*std+mean and 3*std-mean. I seem to have the mean plotting but can't work out the std! Thanks

```
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

    for element in df_na.loc[:, 'Ag_ppb':'Zr_ppb']:
        temp_df = df_na.loc[:, ['Date', element]].dropna()
        fig =plt.figure()
        plt.scatter(temp_df['Date'], temp_df[element],c='black',s=10)
        plt.plot(temp_df['Date'],[df_na[element].mean()]*len(x))
        plt.xlabel('Date')
        plt.xticks(rotation =90, fontsize=5)
        plt.ylabel(element)
        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use dataframe.std():

```
df_na.std(axis=0,skipna=True)[element]
```

Answer (score 0):

So I incorporated the above which works, see below:

```
plt.plot(temp_df['Date'],[temp_df[element].mean(axis=0,skipna=True)]*len(x), c='red',label='Mean')
```

but the following won't plot the 3* std + mean .

```
 plt.plot(temp_df['Date'],[temp_df[element].mean()]+[temp_df[element].std(axis=0,skipna=True)*3]*len(x),label='3xstd')
```

Answer (score 0):

The above worked but don't adding the mean to 3*std doesn't plot as a line.